# Is there something like lsblk for network interfaces?

Tags: networking, command-line

Is there a Linux command that visualizes configured network interfaces in a tree view, just like `lsblk` does for block devices?

The output of such a program could for example look like this (bottom-up-approach):

```
eth0   
└─bond0
  ├─bond0.42
  │ └─br42
  └─bond0.43
    └─br43
eth1
└─bond0
  ├─bond0.42
  │ └─br42
  └─bond0.43
    └─br43
tap100i0
└─br42
tap100i1
└─br43
tap101i0
└─br42
tap101i1
└─br43
```

or this (top-down-approach):

```
br42
├─bond0.42
│ └─bond0
│   ├─eth0
│   └─eth1
├─tap100i0
└─tap101i0
br43
├─bond0.43
│ └─bond0
│   ├─eth0
│   └─eth1
├─tap100i1
└─tap101i1
```

Note: I am not looking for a tool that produces this exact output, but rather asking if anyone knows a command with a similar result.

Comment: did you try  `ip addr` ??

Comment: yes, but `ip addr` returns a flat list of network interfaces, not a hierarchical tree view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have search for an option in existing utilities but I have not found any. Nevertheless the desired functionality is useful from my point of view. So I did a simple bash script that parses `ip link show` command and prints something similar to the desired output in the question:

```
$ ./nettree.sh -u
eth3
    bond1
       bond0
eth2
    bond0
eth1
    bond0
eth0
lupen3
    bond1
       bond0
lo
lxcbr0
virbr0
veth6404e35
    docker0
```

I pushed the script to github: https://github.com/zabojcampula/show-net-devices-tree

Comment: I forked your script, and ended up reimplementing the main logic differently. See my answer to this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the [pre-existing Accepted Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340006/127903) to this Q, and used it for years myself.

Recently I found myself updating/tweaking it a bit to detect VLAN device hierarchies, PPPoE, and other things. Then basically completely [rewrote it](https://github.com/AlexStragies/lsnetdev/blob/master/nettree.sh).

In contrast to the AA the files/folders under `/sys/class/net/` and `/proc/net/` are examinded to build the hierarchy.

Output formats are `tree`, `utf`, and `graphviz`. It also also querying remote ssh-hosts with the `-s` option:

```
$ ./nettree.sh 
meshif
└── bat0
    └── vswitch
        ├── hmv
        │   └── home
        └── iso
wlp2s0

$ ./nettree.sh -d -l
wlp2s0
home ━┓
      ┗━ hmv ━┓
              ┗━ vswitch ━┓
                          ┗━ bat0 ━┓
                                   ┗━ meshif
iso ━┓
     ┗━ vswitch ━┓
                 ┗━ bat0 ━┓
                          ┗━ meshif

$ ./nettree.sh -d -G
graph iftree {
  "wlp2s0"[label="wlp1s0", class="wireless"];
  "switch"[label="switch", class="switch"];
  "hmv"[label="homev", class="virtual"];
  "bat0"[label="bat0", class="virtual"];
  "home"[label="home", class="bond"];
  "iso"[label="iso", class="virtual"];
  "meshif"[label="usbxg2a", class="wireless"];
  "home" -- "hmv"[label=""];
  "hmv" -- "vswitch"[label=""];
  "iso" -- "vswitch"[label=""];
  "vswitch" -- "bat0"[label=""];
  "bat0" -- "meshif"[label=""];
}
```